# display a string as a modal with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, modal-dialog

I am trying display a string that contains a full bootstrap modal. The onClick event downloads the string, adds it to a existing div but fails to show it.

document:

```
<div id="HTTPrequestModalDiv"></div>
```

input onclick:

`HTTPrequest ( 'ID7', 'colorTable.php' ); 
$( '#ModalHTTPRequest' ).modal('show') ;`

The function `HTTPrequest`:

```
function HTTPrequest ( ID , url  ) {    
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
Http.open("GET", url  + "?ID=" + ID );
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => { 
 document.getElementById('HTTPrequestModalDiv').innerHTML = Http.responseText ;
 }
$.getScript(  url  ) ;
$( '#ModalHTTPRequest' ).modal('show') ;    
}
```

All steps work only `modal.show` does not. I have to click twice to make the modal appear. I tried to put the modal.open statement twice in the code ...

- How can I make the modal show immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but this works now. Probably jquery magic ...

```
$('#div' + random ).load(  dataURL,function(){
$('#ModalHTTPRequest' + random ).modal({show:true});
```

Instead of adding an HTTP request result to an innerHTML, the jquery load function does the trick.

This page explains it: [How to Load Dynamic Content in Bootstrap Modal][1]